# TypeORM: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to work out why the following raw SQL works perfectly with PostGres, whereas the SQL generated via TypeORM does not.

Running this works:

```sql
SELECT symbol, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
FROM update_history
WHERE exchange = 'NYSE'
AND data_type = 'companyRecord'
GROUP BY symbol
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/yocl-rBq

Whereas, the TypeORM sql generated by the following:

```js
const result = this.repository
  .createQueryBuilder('h1')
  .select(['MAX(h1.createdAt) AS created_at', 'h1.symbol'])
  .where('h1.exchange = :exchange', { exchange })
  .andWhere('h1.dataType = :dataType', { dataType })
  .groupBy('h1.symbol')
  .orderBy({ created_at: 'ASC' })
  .take(limit)
  .getMany();

/* Produces this:

SELECT "h1"."symbol" AS "h1_symbol", 
  MAX("h1"."created_at") AS created_at 
FROM "update_history" "h1" 
WHERE "h1"."exchange" = 'NYSE'
AND "h1"."data_type" = 'companyRecord' 
GROUP BY "h1"."symbol" 
ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 5000
*/
```

Example (second select box): https://dbfiddle.uk/yocl-rBq

Returns the following error:

> QueryFailedError: column "h1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

If I add `h1.id` to the `GROUP BY` clause, the query no longer returns the correct result set, as it is effectively different.

As you can see from the DBFiddle links, both generated SQL queries work outside of TypeORM.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is h1.id ? I could not find it inside of your query select part.

Comment: It's an alias generated by TypeORM, it's specified here, createQueryBuilder('h1')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `getMany()` which always adds `id` field in the `select`. The query that you've pasted has most probably been logged before adding `getMany()`. Try setting `logging: true` in your `ormconfig.js` and you'll see the exact query being fired.

You should use `getRawMany()` and you'll be able to get the exact query and also the desired result.

Comment: Ahh got it, ok many thanks. I'm trying to avoid getRawMany() as that means I'll have to map the result to an entity myself. Is there anything I can change to make getMany() work?

Comment: No. `getMany` always adds primary key to your query. The query that you’re doing is not even mapping to your entity at least logically. Why do you want to map this to your entity class? Let’s say, even if you do it manually, you might mistake `MAX(created_at)` with `created_at` some point later in your code.

Comment: OK got it, thanks! The reason being, my entities are using camelCase, whereas the table fields use snake_case. I'll just manually map the casing myself.

Comment: Sweet. You save my day